# Wildfly em produção não recupera valores de properties e scripts SQL

Tags: java, html, sql, spring, wildfly

Estou utilizando um ambiente de desenvolvimento e outro de produção, no ambiente de desenvolvimento utilizando o conceito de i18N (Internacionalização) é recuperado corretamente por exemplo o valor de `label.carro` que é `Carro`, porém coloquei no servidor de produção (que não possui nenhum cliente), e é retornado no caption no HTML o valor `label.carro` e não `Carro` como deveria ser retornado, ou seja, não esta lendo o arquivo de extensão `.properties` incluido no Java Build Path do projeto.

O mesmo acontece ao recuperar um arquivo `.sql`, retorna o erro `NullPointerException` ao percorrer uma lista com os arquivos SQL.

**Segue a imagem dos arquivos no Project Explorer**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código que recupera os arquivos com extensão .properties**:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class MessageI18n {

    private Locale locale;

    public MessageI18n(Locale locale) {     
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public MessageI18n() {
         locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    }

    public String getMessage(String code) {     
        ResourceBundleMessageSource m = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        m.setBasenames("MessageI18N/ValidationMessages","MessageI18N/messages");

        return  m.getMessage(code, null, this.locale);
    }   
}
```

**Código que recupera os arquivos SQL, porém ocorre o erro de NullPointerException ao entrar no laço de repetição**:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File folder = new File(classLoader.getResource("dataBaseVersion").getFile());        

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
         // Resto dos códigos
    }
```

O que me intriga é por que consegue ler os arquivos em modo de desenvolvimento, mas não em modo de produção e as configurações são iguais?

Comment: Você saberia dizer se os arquivos estão rodando dentro de um JAR/WAR/EAR no servidor? Ou se o conteúdo desse JAR/WAR/EAR está explodido? E no ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Comment: Você usa maven para fazer o build da aplicação?

Comment: Sim, em um WAR. E utilizo maven na aplicação para as dependências.

Comment: Se você colocar os properties na pasta `src/main/resources/MessageI18N` ao invés de `src/main/java/MessageI18N`, e fazer algo parecido com os SQLs, o que acontece?

Comment: Fiz o que você falou, testamos em outras duas máquinas, a com IP externo (que é a produção) e a com IP interno, funcionou tranquilamente nas máquinas internas, mas não na externa que utiliza Windows Server 2008. Agora resta saber o por quê e deveria funcionar em todas por causa da JVM e Wildfly com mesmas configurações.

Comment: O detalhe é que o servidor de produção esta em lingua inglesa, enquanto os outros em lingua portuguesa.

Comment: As SQLs funcionaram pelo menos?

Comment: Arrumei o erro, como o servidor estava em Inglês e não havia as properties em `en` ocorreu esse problema, pensei que pegava do cliente e passava para o servidor a linguagem do cliente, para não pegar a lingua do servidor e sim do cliente acredito que é questão para outra pergunta. Quanto a do sql não consegui resolver ainda, mas invés de pegar o caminho de onde esta o deployment esta pegando um arquivo que não existe na pasta de documentos do usuário.